# Javascript object checking not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i made this navigation menu that takes values from object property, but when i am missing object property i want javascript to give me alert message.
I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
 /*
    if(menu[nextMenu].menuList=="undefined"){
            alert('error');
    }
    */
```

I am using jQuery.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>this is the title</title>
<style type="text/css">

ul li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px;
    background:grey;
    color:white;    
}
ul li:hover{
    background:#484848;
    cursor:pointer;
}

ul{
    width:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<button class="back-btn">Back</button> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
var menuNr = 0;
var menuListNr = 0;
var menuIndex = 0;
var nextMenu = 0;
var history1 = [0];

var menu = [{
    menuName: 'menu list',
    menuList: ['new game', 'options', 'credit'], // MENU LIST 0
    menuIndex: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    menuName: 'new game',
    menuList: ['easy', 'normal', 'hard'], // NEW GAME 1
    menuIndex: [4, 5, 6]
  }, {
    menuName: 'options',
    menuList: ['sound', 'video', 'keyboard'], // OPTIONS 2
    menuIndex: [7, 8, 9]
  }, {
    menuName: 'credit',
    menuList: ['designers', 'voiceactors', 'programmers'], // CREDIT 3
    menuIndex: [10, 11, 12]
  }, {
  }, {
  }, {
  }, {
  }, {
    menuName: 'credit',
    menuList: ['brightness', 'color'], // VIDEO 8
    menuIndex: [10, 11, 12]
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < menu[menuNr].menuList.length; i++) {
  $('.menu ul').append('<li>' + menu[menuNr].menuList[i] + '</li>');
}

$('.menu ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var selectedIndex = $(this).index();
  nextMenu = menu[menuNr].menuIndex[selectedIndex];

  $('.menu ul').empty();

  for (var i = 0; i < menu[nextMenu].menuList.length; i++) {
    $('.menu ul').append('<li>' + menu[nextMenu].menuList[i] + '</li>');
  }
  menuNr = nextMenu;

  history1.push(menuNr);
  console.log(history1);
});

$('.back-btn').on('click', function() {
  var x = history1.length;
  x -= 2;

  if (x < 0) {
    x = 0;
    return;
  }

  menuNr = x;
  history1.pop();

  $('.menu ul').empty();

  for (var i = 0; i < menu[menuNr].menuList.length; i++) {
    $('.menu ul').append('<li>' + menu[menuNr].menuList[i] + '</li>');
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the jquery? do you want `var menu = $(".menu").attr("menuList");` ?

Comment: take a look at the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator for the `=='undefined'` check, note `undefined == null`, `undefined  -> falsy`, `null -> falsy`, `undefined !== null`

Comment: Where do you want to add this test in your code? If you want to e.g. check if `menu[menuNr].menuList`  is `undefined` then it should be `menu[menuNr].menuList === undefined` (without the `"`)

Comment: You've included jQuery 1.6.1, but the `on` method of a jQuery object was not added until jQuery 1.7, so right now, I'm seeing an error about his before I even get to that code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you want to write

```
if(!menu[nextMenu] || typeof menu[nextMenu].menuList === "undefined"){
  alert('error');
}
```

It checks if menu property exists, if no - it skips rest. Then it checks if `menuList` is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if(menu[nextMenu].menuList=="undefined" || 
menu[nextMenu].menuList == "" ||  
menu[nextMenu].menuList=="null"){
        alert('error');
}
```

Not all browsers will return the same thing if you try to target a non-existing DOM node. Some will return null, some "unidentified" and some just as an empty space.

You can also test against the DOM node length. If it does not exist, it will return 0.

Comment: An API should never return a **string** containing `undefined` or `null` for a not existing element, it should return the **value** `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: He is trying to dynamically identify if an element exists in the DOM or not. The jQuery return on that test will vary depending on the browser - and can be any of the afformentioned return statements.

Comment: jQuery was written to get around browser differences. So even if the browsers might return **strings** for the check if an element exists int he DOM - which they don't - then the jQuery function would normalise this to a result that is equal across the browsers. A test if an element is in DOM based on a selector would be  `$(selector).length > 0`, to check if an existing DOM element is attached to the DOM would be `jQuery.contains( container, contained)` and returns the **values** `true` or `false`. Not even at the time of IE 6 I had to deal with **strings** containing `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Actually, you are wrong. jQuery does nothing for return statements. It only normalizes the js functionally. It does not dictate return statements, as return statements are wholly browser dependent. Thus every single tutorial or instructional out there advises to capture both null, "", and undefined OR simply test against object return length.